# Java - Send request/response to hyperlinked servlet when link is clicked

Tags: java, servlets, request

I have tried Googling this and I have also searched StackOverflow, but I haven't yet found answers to this question (Maybe I'm just bad at searching?).

**Servlet A**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String sortBy = request.getParameter("sortBy");
    String orderBy = request.getParameter("orderBy");
    // Send request and response if this link is clicked
    out.println("<a href=\"/Fabflix/servlet/SortResults?sortBy=" 
                          + sortBy + "&orderBy=" + orderBy + "\">Title</a>);
    ArrayList<Movies> movies = ... //Fill up the movies arraylist
    request.setAttribute("movies", movies);
}
```

**SortResults Servlet**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
{
    // Receive request here so I can call:
    ArrayList<Movie> movies = (ArrayList<Movie>) request.getAttribute("movies");
}
```

How can I send the request/response over from `Servlet A` only when the link is clicked?

Comment: The anchor tag `<a>` just requires a valid URL to which a Servlet is mapped. This should work, if your mappings are correct. What do you get with this code? Could you please tell?

Comment: You need to pass values as request parameters that you want to receive in  the `SortResults` Servlet. `request.getAttribute("movies", movies)` will not work, since you're triggering a brand new request with `<a>`.

Comment: `movies` is null, because I couldn't pass it through a session.

Comment: I'm not sure how you do what you just described, could I please get some code?

Comment: You can get a list of movies in the `SortResults` Servlet through `request.getAttribute("movies")` only if you use `RequestDispatchar` (in your case, you want to redirect (not forward) a request through `<a>`). In your case, you're using a link, therefore, you need to pass it as a query-string parameter after appending it to `StringBuilder` using the `append()` method that you can get in resulting Servlet by using `request.getParameterValues("movies")`. If this list is too large then, you need to store it in the session.

Comment: Sorry I'm still having a hard time understanding what you are saying. Mind showing me in code what you're saying?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46135/discussion-between-dtgee-and-tiny)